# Erro ao tenta adicionar números em uma array de int32

Tags: c#, array

Estou tentando armazenar uma array de `ints` para usar periostealmente, mas deparei com um erro de sintaxe na parte . `{ 4, 7, 8, 9, 10 }`

```
    private Int32[] m_FluxosPlataformas = null;
    public Int32[] FluxosPlataformas
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_FluxosPlataformas == null)
            {
                m_FluxosPlataformas =  { 4, 7, 8, 9, 10 } ; 
            }
            return m_FluxosPlataformas;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você tentou substituir a linha: m_FluxosPlataformas =  { 4; 7, 8, 9, 10 } ; 

Por: m_FluxosPlataformas =  { 4, 7, 8, 9, 10 } ;  ???

Comment: Sim, mas mesmo assim da erro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O array é um tipo-referência e precisa ser inicializado.

Substitua o código:

```
m_FluxosPlataformas =  { 4, 7, 8, 9, 10 } ;
```

Por:

```
m_FluxosPlataformas = new Int32[] { 4, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

Comment: Só pra comentar `new Int32[] {...}` pode ser trocado por `new [] {...}`